# Looking up tickers for different time periods in a loop with quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm able to loop through and calculate the overnight/over-weekend returns for a list of tickers when the time period is the same for every ticker, but am having trouble when the time period I want to look up is different for each ticker.

For example, with:

```
symbols <- c("AAPL", "GOOG"," MSFT")
dates <- as.Date(c("2015-01-04", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06"))
example.df <- data.frame(tickers, dates)
example.df
  tickers dates
1    AAPL 2015-01-04
2    GOOG 2015-01-05
3    MSFT 2015-01-06
```

I'd want the overnight return for AAPL between 2015-01-04 and 2015-01-05, for GOOG between 2015-01-05 and 2015-01-06, etc. If it was a Friday, I'd want the next Monday.

I can can get what I'm looking for by looking up each individual ticker like this:

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
# date range accounts for weekends
getSymbols("AAPL", from = "2016-01-04", to = "2016-01-08")
data <- as.data.frame(AAPL)
colnames(data) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
# overnight return calculation
data$overnight.return <- data$open / lag(data$close, default = 0) - 1
data$overnight.return <- paste(round(data$overnight.return * 100, 3), "%",sep= "") 
# the overnight/over-weekend returns for the specified date
data.df.final <- slice(data, 2)
```

Of course that's terribly slow.
Here's as far as I was able to get trying to make a loop out of it:

```
# needs to be a loop itself and inside the other 'for' loop somehow I think
symbol.list <- example.df[,1]
start <-  data[,2]
end <- data[,2] + days(3) 

results <- NULL
for (i in symbol.list) {
  data <- getSymbols(Symbols = i, 
                     src = "yahoo", 
                     from = start, to = end, 
                     auto.assign = FALSE)
  if (inherits(data, 'try-error')) next
  colnames(data) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
  data <- as.data.frame(data)
  data <- cbind(date = rownames(data), data)
  data$overnightRtn <- as.vector(data$open / lag(data$close, default = 0) - 1)
  data$overnightRtn <- paste(round(data$overnightRtn * 100, 3), "%") 
  data <- slice(data, 2)
  results <- bind_rows(results, data)
  }
```

How can I add the date looping aspect to the above ticker loop?

Comment: Hi RyGuy. Could you add some example/reproducible data? Also, I don't understand very well the problem. However, if you want to sum the info per ticker, and you have a table with values+dates and another with tickers+rangeDate,  I rather join both tables, so that the information about the ticker, value, date will be together withe the start date, and end date. With all that in the same table, you can just use aggregate or an equivalent in dplyr or data.table to do the final math.

Comment: @Carlos Alberto, thanks for taking a look. In my first paragraph after "For example, with:" there's the example data frame I'm using. The salient question I have is - how can I use quant mod to loop through and look up tickers in a data frame, if all those tickers correspond to different dates? In my example, I want to retrieve the info for AAPL on 2015-01-04(and the next couple days), for GOOG on 2015-01-05(and the next couple days) etc.  Then bind all those results together in one df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this is what you are looking for. See that I'm using an index, not the actual list, so I can refer to every element of your data frame (it is not optimized, but it is doing the job you described in the function):

```
symbols <- c("AAPL", "GOOG"," MSFT")              ## " MSFT" has an extra space
dates <- as.Date(c("2015-01-04", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06"))
example.df <- data.frame(tickers=symbols, dates)  ## there was an error here in your example.

symbol.list <- trimws(example.df[,1])
start <-  as.Date(example.df[,2])
end <- as.Date(example.df[,2]) + days(3) 

results <- NULL
for (i in 1:NROW(symbol.list)) {
  try(dataX <- getSymbols(Symbols = symbol.list[i], 
                     src = "yahoo", 
                     from = start[i], to = end[i], 
                     auto.assign = FALSE),silent=T)
  if (!exists("dataX")) {cat("Error in ",i,"\n");next}
  colnames(dataX) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
  dataX <- as.data.frame(dataX)
  dataX <- cbind(date = rownames(dataX), dataX)
  dataX$overnightRtn <- as.vector(dataX$open / lag(dataX$close, default = 0) - 1)
  dataX$overnightRtn <- paste(round(dataX$overnightRtn * 100, 3), "%") 
  data2 <- slice(dataX, 2);rm(dataX)
  results <- if (is.null(results)) data2 else rbind(results, data2)
}
```

Comment: .@Carlos Alberto, sorry for my sloppiness on the example and thank you for bearing with me, and for your detailed solution. The only part that's not working is the error handling. Try: `symbols <- c("AAPL", "GOOG","BADTICKER","MSFT");             
dates <- as.Date(c("2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06"))` Any ideas how to fix this? I've got lots of bad tickers so it's a problem.